# Ruby version error on deployment with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting ' Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0' when I am trying to deploy with Capistrano.
my gemfile specifying 2.3.3

```
ruby "2.3.3"

00:27 bundler:install
  01 /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.3 do bundle install --path /var/www/mypath/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
  01 Warning, new version of rvm available '1.29.1', you are using older version '1.29.0'.
  01 You can disable this warning with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=0 >> ~/.rvmrc
  01 You can enable  auto-update  with:    echo rvm_autoupdate_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc
  01 Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

Comment: Please share the top section of your Gemfile, where the Ruby version is specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what the problem is from looking at this, but here is how I would debug it.

Check your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and verify it is showing 2.3.3.  Also Capistrano pulls directly from the repository rather than uploading your local files so verify your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock on the remote machine have the right versions.  If they don't, verify you have committed the latest Gemfile and Gemfile.lock and pushed them up to your repository.  You can also try just running bundle on the remote machine to take Capistrano out of the equation.